# Print statistics for every character in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is to take a file's data and print out the percentage of each character in file but I don't want to use duplicates. I need to print just one character with a relevant percentage point. Below is the snippet.

```
for all_char in text:
    char_counter = 0 
    if count_char(text, all_char) > 1:
        perc1 = 100 / len(text) * count_char(text, all_char)
        print("{0} - {1}%".format(all_char, round(perc1, 2)))
        with open(filename, "w") as w:        #<-------- I need a code to remove a single character
            w.truncate(char_counter)
            char_counter += 1

    elif count_char(text, all_char) == 1:
        perc2 = 100 * count_char(text, all_char) / len(text)
        print("{0} - {1}%".format(all_char, round(perc2, 2)))
        char_counter += 1
```

Above I made a variable called `char_counter` which will be increased after every iteration and the function called `count_char` will tell, how many times each character is used in file and if that number is higher than 1 the character must be deleted from the file means that it will print only once. This is the base idea but the code gives me an error.

Comment: So you want stats? Or you want to modify (remove something from) the file?

Comment: i need an efficient way to do what i need. I need to print characters from file with a relevant percentage point

Answer (score 2):

You can get the character counts of the entire file by using a `Counter` over the characters.  Then the percentage of each character is `count for that character/total count`.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

with open(filename) as f:
    counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(f))

total = sum(counts.values())

for character, count in counts.items():
    print('{:<2} - {:>6.2f}%'.format(repr(character)[1:-1], (count/total) * 100))
```

For the text

```
Mary had a little lamb.
```

This prints

```
M  -   4.17%
a  -  16.67%
r  -   4.17%
y  -   4.17%
   -  16.67%
h  -   4.17%
d  -   4.17%
l  -  12.50%
i  -   4.17%
t  -   8.33%
e  -   4.17%
m  -   4.17%
b  -   4.17%
.  -   4.17%
\n -   4.17%
```

Comment: You should display "0.04" or "4.0 %".  Using "0.04%" is incorrect and in fact means 4/10,000, instead of what you mean to mean, 4/100.

Comment: i used used code and created a variable witch contained this code:                   
count / total * 100                                                                                            this is a simple way to have better percentage point instead of having 0.4% you will have 40% and also you can use some function like round to make it even more useful like so:                                                               
data = count / total * 100
        print("{!r} - {:.2f}%".format(character, round(data, 3)))

Comment: @irakli The string formatting `{:.2f}` actually already takes care of the rounding.  You can feed it different precisions if you want, `{:.5f}` is rounding to 5 decimal places.  That will give values like `4.16667%` in the above.